# Upper bound of number of triangles in an edge-colored graph, given that none of the triangles are rainbow.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

> Let $G$ be a simple edge-coloured graph with $m$ edges. Assume furthermore that it does not contain a rainbow triangle, (i.e a triangle such that each edge has different color) and each color class in $G$ has size at most $k$. Let $t(G)$ be number of triangles contained in $G$. Prove:
> $$
> t(G) \leq \frac{1}{2} m(k-1)
> $$

Since the triangles are not rainbow, each one of them has a dominant color, i.e., at least two of the three edges in the triangle are in that color. This also gives a partition of the triangles based on the dominant colors, so I’m thinking of upper bounding the number of triangles $t_i$ dominant in color $i$, summing up the bounds across all colors, and hopefully get a bound on $t(G)$.

Now any $i$-dominant triangle use at least $2$ of the $m_i$ edges having color $i$. And we know $m_i \leq k$ for all $i$. So we have:
$$t_i \leq {m_i \choose 2} = \frac{1}{2}m_i(m_i - 1) \leq \frac{1}{2}m_i(k-1)$$

We note that the $m_i$’s partition $m$, so when summing up the $t_i$’s across all color classes, we get:
$$t(G) = \sum t_i \leq \frac{1}{2} m (k-1)$$

**Note:** The following is my first attempt, which was wrong. Also there was a typo in the question that I was not aware of.

> I let $[r]$ be the color classes, and single out a color $i$. The classes $[r] \setminus \{i\}$ have at least $k(r-1)$ edges in total, so $i$ has at most $m - k(r-1)$ edges. Therefore:
> $$t_i \leq \frac{m_i}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2} (m - k(r-1)),$$
>
> where $m_i$ is the number of edges colored $i$, and equality of the first $\leq$ is achieved when each of the $i$-dominant triangles contains $2$ edges colored $i$.
>
> Summing up the above bound across all colors, we get:
> $$t(G) \leq \frac{1}{2}r(m - k(r-1))$$
>
> While I can upper bound $r$ with $\lfloor \frac{m}{k} \rfloor$, I’m stuck at lower bounding it to make the above work. How should I proceed?

Comment: I think there are some bugs here: If you single out a colorclass $i$ with $l$ edges then you can have $l$ triangles which are dominated by $i$. Consider a star-graph with all edges colored red and add a cycle graph (on the non-star-vertices) colored in blue. Blue will not dominate any triangle while red will dominate as many triangles as it has edges.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the comment. I will need to revise my argument.

Comment: I believe I have a counterexample when $m=6$ and $k=2$. Let $G$ be the complete graph on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, where edges $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are colored black, and all other edges are colored white. $G$ is rainbow-triangle-free, and $t(G)=4$, despite $\frac12m(k-1)=\frac12\cdot 6\cdot (2-1)=3$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest there’s a typo in the question. The color classes should have size at most $k$ instead of at least. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I use your idea from yesterday to come up with a new proof. Please have a look.

Comment: That's it, that's the proof! Well done :)